# How can I fix "operator does not exist: text = uuid" when using Haskell's postgres-simple library to perform a multi-row insert?

Tags: sql, postgresql, haskell

I am using the postgres-simple library to insert into the `eligible_class_passes` table. Which is essentially a join table representing a many to many relationship.

I am using the [`executeMany`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:executeMany) function from the `postgres-simple` to do a multi row insert.

```hs
updateEligibleClassPasses :: Connection -> Text -> Text -> [Text] -> IO Int64
updateEligibleClassPasses conn tenantId classTypeId classPassTypeIds =
  withTransaction conn $ do
    executeMany
      simpleConn
      [sql| 
      INSERT INTO eligible_class_passes (class_type_id, class_pass_type_id)
      SELECT upd.class_type_id::uuid, upd.class_pass_type_id::uuid
      FROM (VALUES (?, ?, ?)) as upd(class_type_id, class_pass_type_id, tenant_id)
      INNER JOIN class_types AS ct
      ON upd.class_type_id::uuid = ct.id
      INNER JOIN subscription_types AS st
      ON class_pass_type_id::uuid = st.id
      WHERE ct.tenant_id = upd.tenant_id::uuid AND st.tenant_id = upd.tenant_id::uuid
      |]
      params
 where
  addParams classPassTypeId = (classTypeId, classPassTypeId, tenantId)
  params = addParams <$> classPassTypeIds
```

When this function is executed with the correct parameters applied I get the following runtime error

```hs
SqlError {sqlState = "42883", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, sqlErrorMsg = "operator does not exist: text = uuid", sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."}
```

However, when translated to SQL without the parameter substitutions (?) the query works correctly when executed in psql.

```sql
INSERT INTO eligible_class_passes (class_type_id, class_pass_type_id)
SELECT upd.class_type_id::uuid, upd.class_pass_type_id::uuid
FROM (VALUES ('863cb5ea-7a68-41d5-ab9f-5344605de500', 'e9195660-fd48-4fa2-9847-65a0ad323bd5', '597e6d7a-092a-49be-a2ea-11e8d85d8f82')) as upd(class_type_id, class_pass_type_id, tenant_id)
INNER JOIN class_types AS ct
ON upd.class_type_id::uuid = ct.id
INNER JOIN subscription_types AS st
ON class_pass_type_id::uuid = st.id
WHERE ct.tenant_id = upd.tenant_id::uuid AND st.tenant_id = upd.tenant_id::uuid;
```

My schema is as follows

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE tenants (
  id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY, 
  name text NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  email text NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now(), 
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now()
);

CREATE TABLE class_types (
  id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY, 
  FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenants (id), 
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now(), 
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now()
);

CREATE TABLE class_pass_types (
  id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY, 
  name TEXT NOT NULL, 
  tenant_id UUID NOT NULL, 
  price Int NOT NULL, 
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now(), 
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now(), 
  FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenants (id)
);

-- Many to many join through table.
-- Expresses class pass type redeemability against class types.
CREATE TABLE eligible_class_passes (
  class_type_id UUID, 
  class_pass_type_id UUID, 
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now(), 
  updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default now(), 
  FOREIGN KEY (class_type_id) REFERENCES class_types (id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (class_pass_type_id) REFERENCES class_pass_types (id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  PRIMARY KEY (
    class_type_id, class_pass_type_id
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help debug your issue, use [`formatQuery`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.2/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:formatQuery) function, then you can see what kind of final query `postgresql-simple` is sending to the server.

Also, I'd recommend using [`UUID`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-types-1.0.3/docs/Data-UUID-Types.html#t:UUID) type from `uuid-types` package, instead of `Text` for the uuids. Using `Text` most likely hides some issues from you (which you'll hopefully see by using `formatQuery`.